# Df(x) of $f:\mathbb R^{n^2}\rightarrow\mathbb R^{n^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives

I am a bit a confused about finding  $Df(x)$ of functions like $f:\mathbb R^{n^2}\rightarrow\mathbb R^{n^2}$. For example the derivative of the function $f:M_n(\mathbb R) \rightarrow Sym_n(\mathbb R)$ given by $f(x)=xx^T$. Could someone explain that to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is the composition of $g:M_n(R)\rightarrow M_n(R)\times M_n(R)$ defined by $g(x)=(x,x^T)$ and $h:M_n(R)\times M_n(R)\rightarrow M_n(R)$ defined by $h(x,y)=xy$.

$g$ is linear thus equal to its differential, and $h$ is bilinear, thus $dh_{(x,y)}(u,v)=uy+xv$. This implies that $df_x(u)= ux^T+xu^T$.